# Deploying to Apollo GraphQL / Express to Vercel from any directory?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, vercel

The tutorial in this article works:

https://medium.com/@sppericat/how-to-setup-an-apollo-graphql-server-on-vercel-cc3f2dd72b3e

However, the server entry point must be in `api/index.js` as shown here:

```
# create the `api` folder, and the server entry point
mkdir api
touch api/index.js
```

...and in `vercel.json`:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```

However, if I try to move `index.js` to any other directory, then Vercel will not execute the Javascript at all and just show the raw Javascript in the browser.

How do you move the server entry point and still tell Vercel to execute it properly?

Also, I've tried to contact the article author (Stéphane P. Péricat) directly, but I'm unable to find his contact info anywhere (just profiles like Github, Twitter, Medium, etc.)